# jQuery Datepicker - How to Get Call a Function on Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker which is loaded with events. When the month is changed to another month, a DB call is made to bring back events & this works fine. However, I need this to also happen when the calendar is first displayed as well as later on with user interaction. Here is my code and to simplify my question, how do I get the "getJsonDate" function to run when the calendar is FIRST being displayed on the screen? I'm almost certain this is something rather elementary but its not jumping out at me.

```
       $(function () {
        function getJsonDate(year, month) {
            var theYear = year;
            var theMonth = month;
            alert('You are in, baby!');
            $.post('GetMonthCalendar', {
                data: { year: theYear, month: theMonth },
                success: function(data) {
                    //TODO: make determination on ResourceScheduleTypeId for correct css
                    var i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar td a:exactly(' + data.data[i]['d'] + ')')
                            .css({ color: 'blue' })
                            .attr('href', data.data[i]['link'])
                            .parent().attr('onclick', '');
                    }

                }
            });
        }


        $.expr[":"].exactly = function (el, i, m) {
            var s = m[3];
            if (!s) return false;
            return eval("/^" + s + "$/i").test($(el).text());
        };
        $('#date').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                Date.prototype.toString = function () { return isNaN(this) ? 'NaN' : [this.getDate(), this.getMonth(), this.getFullYear()].join('/'); };
                d = new Date(dateText);
                //alert(d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear());
                getJsonDate(d.getFullYear(), d.getDate());
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                //alert(year + ", " + month);
                getJsonDate(year, month);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$('#date').datepicker({/*your stuff*/}).click(function(e) { getJsonDate(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1); });` You will need the plus one because month is returned on a 0 index

Comment: should i submit it as an answer? lol

Answer (score 0):

Since `datepicker` inherits from [`Widget`](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget), I think you can add a [`create` callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#event-create) that will be executed once the widget has been initialized.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    // …
    create: function(event, ui) {
        getJsonDate(/* year, month */)
    }
})
```

Comment: it looks like the datepicker has a "beforeShow" as well. I'll try both ways and report back.

Comment: create does not work, and beforeShow does not work.. :'(

Answer (score 0):

The question is over 10 years old, but I recently encountered a similar problem and found a solution using the `setTimeout` method.

Here is my answer:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    // your code 
});

setTimeout(function() {
  let selectedDate = $('#date').datepicker('getDate'); 
  let year = selectedDate.getFullYear(); 
  let month = selectedDate.getMonth();
    getJsonDate(year, month);
}, 0);
```

The setTimeout delay is set to zero.

This means that the getJsonDate will be executed after the datepicker has fully initialized.